# How to change image in card on hover dynamically in Vue js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to add 2 images in the card on hover in Vue.

When I hover over the card I want a different image and if I remove hovering it should different.

Here is my HTML:

```js
<div class="services">
    <h1>Our Services</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div
        v-for="service in services"
        :key="service.title"
        @mouseover="isMouseOver = !isMouseOver"
        class="card"
        :style="
          isMouseOver
            ? 'background-image:' + service.icon + ';'
            : 'background-image:' + service.iconGlow + ';'
        "
      >
        <div class="face face1">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>{{ service.title }}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="face face2">
          <div class="content">
            <p>
              {{ service.description }}
            </p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isMouseOver: true,
      services: [
        {
          icon: require("@/assets/icons/services/webIcon.svg"),
          iconGlow: require("@/assets/icons/services/WebLogoGlow.svg"),
          title: "Web Development",
          description:
            "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Quas cum cumque minus iste veritatis provident at.",
        },
        {
          icon: require("@/assets/icons/services/AppIcon.svg"),
          iconGlow: require("@/assets/icons/services/AppIconGlow.svg"),
          title: "Mobile Application Development",
          description:
            "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Quas cum cumque minus iste veritatis provident at.",
        },
        {
          icon: require("@/assets/icons/services/Cross.svg"),
          iconGlow: require("@/assets/icons/services/CrossLogo2.svg"),
          title: "Computer Application Development",
          description:
            "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Quas cum cumque minus iste veritatis provident at.",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container .card .face.face1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  /* background-image: url("../assets/icons/services/WebLogoGlow.svg"); */

  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.container .card:hover .face.face1 {
  background: #9376cf;
  transform: translateY(0);
  /* background-image: url("../assets/icons/services/webIcon.svg"); */

  background-size: 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I want these background images in CSS to be dynamic. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using two images from the internet on your ":style="isMouseOver..." ? I'd try that first, just to see if it's a problem on your logic or on your images URLs.

Comment: you could also use the image as a background image. Then use the `:hover` selector to chose a different background image

Comment: I already fixed it by adding url :style="
          isMouseOver
            ? 'background-image url:(' + service.icon + ');'
            : 'background-image:url(' + service.iconGlow + ');'
        "
.
but adding like you said background image to each card will increase the css code I am trying to make it dynamic

Comment: but now the issue is that when I hover over 1 card it changes state of all cards , i want it only on the one card